# non-proportional stretching with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, perspective

I want to correct a photo of an object going to "horizon" using imagemagick (like the road example here: http://gallery.hd.org/_exhibits/travel/_more2007/_more02/desert-road-straight-into-distance-horizon-vanishing-point-through-Atacama-desert-arid-dry-rocky-barren-whispy-cloud-above-south-of-Antofagasta-Chile-1-AJHD.jpg).

First I corrected the trapezoid error by using -distort perspective. Finally I got parallel lines (e.g. for the road). Since the objects become closer at large distances (see the centerline markers at the road) I want also correct this to get a top view of the road like from an helicopter or from space (like e.g. here (rotated by 90 degree): http://image.yaymicro.com/rz_1210x1210/0/bf7/top-view-of-road-intersection-bf7ffc.jpg).

This means that I need to stretch the image but with an amount of zero in the foreground and an (quadratic?) increasing amount in the background. How can I manage this using imgemagick? At least the image should have the aspect ratio of the original object at the end, i.e. for the road example to be a few meters wide and a few thousend meters long. Only scaling doesn't help since then the foreground is streched with the same amount than the background.

Thank you all in advance for helping with this difficult topic.

Comment: I cannot access your image :-)

Comment: I found this via google ... hmm ... this is comparable:  http://vietroad.org/TheRoad.jpg

Comment: Basically it is a kind of trigonometric math but if I have a function describing the amount of "local" stretching I don't know how to apply to imagemagick.

Comment: I do not understand from your description how exactly you want to stretch the image. Should it be horizontally? Vertically? Or how else?

Comment: Well I have the photo of a road becomming smaller close to the horizon and want to transform it to a helicopter view with right ratio between width and length. I don't care about the final orientation of the road.